# Change the Owner access Charlie root to user at a media device, possible?

Tags: freebsd, root, non-root-user, ownership

how can I change owner access from Charlie root to user access for my media devices (partitions `/media/da0s1`) on FreeBSD?

Answer (score 1):

You can use chown for that.  As in "`chown myuser:mygroup /dev/da0s1`"

If you want this to be permanent (this example is similar to a cdrom entry in my own machine), then put the following in /etc/devfs.conf:

```
own    da0s1   myuser:mygroup
```

note that this file is only consulted when the device is created (at boot time or when attached).

Comment: devfs.rules(5) would seem to be the better choice.